# Custom Formatter for two slick grids on same page

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I am rendering two slick grids in a single page and I have written a custom formatter for displaying date picker on page load instead of doing it in editable mode(default functionality).

I am distinguishing the two grids with a grid column name.

```
function DateFormatter (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {

      var template = null;
      var rowString = row.toString();
      var cellString = cell.toString();


      if(dataContext.seasonName!= null){

          var hiddenIdentitySeason = "#dpSeason"+rowString+cellString;

          var dateIdentitySeason = "#seasonDateInput"+rowString+cellString;
      $(hiddenIdentitySeason).datepicker({
             buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",buttonImageOnly: true,changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,showOn: "both", onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
             $(dateIdentitySeason).val(dateText);
       }
       });
      template = '<input type="text" id = "seasonDateInput'+rowString+cellString+'" style="width:75px;" value='+value+'></input><input type="hidden" id="dpSeason'+rowString+cellString+'"  ></input>';
      }else if(dataContext.foodName!= null){
          var hiddenIdentity = "#dpFood"+rowString+cellString;
          var dateIdentity = "#foodDateInput"+rowString+cellString;
          $(hiddenIdentity).datepicker({
                 buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",buttonImageOnly: true,changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,showOn: "both", onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                 $(dateIdentity).val(dateText);
           }
           });
          template = '<input type="text" id = "foodDateInput'+rowString+cellString+'" style="width:75px;" value='+value+'></input><input type="hidden" id="dpFood'+rowString+cellString+'"  ></input>';
      }


      return template;

  }
```

But date picker icon is not getting displayed which means datepicker() is not called.

If I write this formatter for only one grid,it works fine as expected.

Code thats works fine for one grid:

```
function DateFormatter (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {

      var rowString = row.toString();
      var cellString = cell.toString();
      var hiddenIdentitySeason = "#dpSeason"+rowString+cellString;        
     var dateIdentitySeason = "#seasonDateInput"+rowString+cellString;
      $(hiddenIdentitySeason).datepicker({
             buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",buttonImageOnly: true,changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,showOn: "both", onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
             $(dateIdentitySeason).val(dateText);
       }
       });
     return '<input type="text" id = "seasonDateInput'+rowString+cellString+'" style="width:75px;" value='+value+'></input><input type="hidden" id="dpSeason'+rowString+cellString+'"  ></input>';  


  }
```

Kindly advice.

Comment: I have a feeling the issue is due to the fact that at the point that you are applying/binding `datepicker`, the `template` has not yet been added to the DOM. Perhaps you could elaborate on exactly what you are doing when you *write this formatter for only one grid*.

Comment: I am applying the custom formatter in the same way without the if else condition.

Comment: And does the other grid still contain the column definition with the formatter usage in it? What order are the grids loaded in?

Comment: yes.If I use the second piece of code,given above for both grids,first works fine on page load.but id conflicts will occur if we use same formatter template for both the grids.First,season grid is created and then food grid is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the commentary, the season grid actually loads the datepicker when the food grid is initializing. If you create only the season grid you should not get the datepicker. This is due to the fact that the template being returned from the formatter is what the datepicker requires in order to properly "bind" itself and is not available within DOM when looked up.

One possible solution is to set a small timeout to allow the function to return the template for SlickGrid to insert into the DOM, thereby allowing jQuery to properly look up the elements. See the following example:

```html
<html>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/examples.css">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js"></script>
  
 
<style>
 
    .ui-datepicker-calendar {
        background-color: #A8A8A8 
    }
    .ui-datepicker-title {
        background-color: #606060
    }
</style>
<div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
<div hidden><span id='dataDump'></span><button id='debugB'>Debug</button></div>
<script>
    
 var grid;
 var data = [];
 
 function DateFormatter (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {

      
      if(columnDef.formatter){
         var id = "DateInput"+row+cell;
         var bind = function() {
          $("#" + id).datepicker({showOn: "button", buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/images/calendar.gif",buttonImageOnly: true});     
         }    
         setTimeout(bind, 250)
      
         return '<input type="text" id = "'+id+  '" style="width:60px;" value='+value+'></input>';
      }
      return value;
  }
  
 var columns = [
    {id: "row", name: "Row", field: "row"}
  ];
   
 for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    columns.push({
      id: "id" + i,
      name: "Id" + i,
      field: i,
      formatter: i%2 === 0 || i%3 === 0 ? DateFormatter : null
    });
  }

  var options = {
    editable: false,
    forceFitColumns: true,
    enableCellNavigation: true
  };


  $(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      var d = (data[i] = {});
      d.row = "Row " + i;
      for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
         if(j%3===0 || j %2 ===0){
               d[j] = Math.round(Math.random() * 10) + "/" + Math.round(Math.random() * 10) + "/2014";
        } 
        else {
          d[j] = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        }
      }
    }

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
      $("#debugB").click(function(){
          console.log("clicked")
          $("#dataDump").text(JSON.stringify(grid.getData()))
      })
    });
</script>

 
</html>
```